# Filtering objects in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have an app that shows a customers health history, where each insertion has an ID. Looks like this:

[image]

I have a search feature, where as you type, i would like the filter the display by the IDs

```
<input id="episode-id-input" placeholder="Search by episode ID..." type="text" class="validate" ng-model="vm.searchEpisodeById">
```

The way my data gets loaded is like this, through an `ng-repeat`:

```
  <div ng-class="{
    'kept'     :person.pastAppointmentStatus == 'KEPT APPT.',
    'cancelled':person.pastAppointmentStatus == 'CANCELLED',
  }" class="past-appointments-meta-holder">


      <div class="meta-holder-title">
        <p class="meta-holder-title-name">
          {{person.activeReferralsType}}
        </p>
        <p class="meta-holder-title-date">
          {{person.activeReferralsDate| date:'MMMM dd, yyyy'}} | {{person.activeReferralsTime}}
        </p>
        <p class="meta-holder-title-status">
          {{person.pastAppointmentStatus}}
        </p>
        <p class="episode-id">
          EPISODE ID: {{person.episodeId}}
        </p>
      </div>
```

The Object looks like this:

```
, "historyContainer" : [
                {
                   "activeReferralsType" : "new patient diabetic eye exam"
                  , "episodeId" : "9876"
                  , "activeReferralsDate" : new Date('1998-10-19')
                  , "activeReferralsTime" : "2:00PM"
                  , "referredFromName" : "Karen Rush, MD"
                  , "referredFromAddressFacilityName" : "Random Family Practice"
                  , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressLineOne" : "1108 Cedar Road"
                  , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressLineTwo" : "Chesapeake"

                }
                ,{
                   "activeReferralsType" : "new patient diabetic eye exam"
                  , "episodeId" : "87678678"
                  , "activeReferralsDate" : new Date('1998-10-19')
                  , "activeReferralsTime" : "2:00PM"
                  , "referredFromName" : "Karen Rush, MD"
                  , "referredFromAddressFacilityName" : "Random Family Practice"
                  , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressLineOne" : "1108 Cedar Road"
                  , "referredFromAddressFacilityAddressLineTwo" : "Chesapeake"

                }
              ]
```

I have never used a filter function in angular before, could someone please show me how I would filter the `ng-repeat` after it has loaded, to show only the `div`s that have the ID typed in by the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. Refer to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9oL94pcj/182/) for full code.

```
  <div class="meta-holder-title" ng-repeat="person in person | filter: { episodeId: searchEpisodeById }">
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it will also filter on basis of activeReferralsType rather than just filtering on basis of ids

Comment: @madhur I got what you mean. I have updated the answer to cater for the situation.

Comment: Thanks! it looks to be correct, however i am getting the error "Error: [filter:notarray] Expected array but received: 0" even though our objects are the same...

Comment: I removed the "track by index" in the ng-repeat and it fixed the issue, but i need the index later on... do you know how to compensate?

Answer (score 0):

You would like to do it this way, hope it helps

```js
function myCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.persons = [
    {episodeId:1},
    {episodeId:2},
    {episodeId:3},
    {episodeId:4},
    {episodeId:5},
    {episodeId:6},
    {episodeId:7}
    ];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app >
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input id="episode-id-input" placeholder="Search by episode ID..." type="text" class="validate" ng-model="search.episodeId">
  <div ng-repeat="person in persons| filter:search">
          <p class="episode-id">
            EPISODE ID: {{person.episodeId}}
          </p>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```